# Hyper-V Ubuntu 10.04 Network hit and miss

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, ubuntu, hyper-v

So I installed 10.04 on Hyper-V R2. While booting up the VM I have a ping -t xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (The Ubuntu Guest IP address) and it actually gets a response for about 10 seconds after you see the login prompt on ubuntu. Then about the time it takes to login you start getting a request timed out. I disabled UFW and rebooted and still nothing. Same results. Any ideas?

It is a legacy adapter as well.

Comment: Is the NIC in the physical host an Intel or Broadcom? Does it have the latest firmware?

Answer (score 0):

Check that it has unique mac address in hyperV , also that you do not have IP conflict :)